# App se cierra al ingresar a un CoroutineScope y escribir palabras en buscador

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy creando por primera vez una app que se comunica con una api

Pero al buscar nombres como "Exit" o "Music" se cierra la app, esto lo coloco porque hay registros que tienen ese nombre.

Metodo de la clase principal

```
    private fun initUI() {
        
        binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                searchByName(query.orEmpty())
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?) = false

        })

        adapter= DdscAdapter{navigateToDetailMod(it)}

        binding.rvSpanishClub.setHasFixedSize(true)
        binding.rvSpanishClub.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.rvSpanishClub.adapter= adapter
    }

    private fun searchByName(query: String) {
        binding.progressBar.isVisible=true
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val myResponse: Response<DdscDataResponse> = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java).getDokidokispanishclubName(query)
            if (myResponse.isSuccessful){
                val response: DdscDataResponse? = myResponse.body()
                if (response != null){
                    runOnUiThread {
                        adapter.updateList(response.mods)
                        binding.progressBar.isVisible = false
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Además, cuando intento acceder a la información detallada, se termina cerrando cuando trato de obtener la info mediante otro CoroutineScope, en la funcion getModInformation() de la clase DetailModActivity

```
    private fun getModInformation(id: String) {
        //Realize algunas depuraciones, pero en esta parte siempre crashea
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val ModDetail =
                getRetrofit().create(ApiService::class.java).getDokidokispanishclubID(id)

            if(ModDetail.body() != null){
                runOnUiThread { createUI(ModDetail.body()!!) }
            }
        }

    }

    private fun createUI(mod: ModInfoDetailResponse) {
        Picasso.get().load(mod.mods_detail.url_img).into(binding.ivModDetail)
        binding.tvTitleModDetail.text= mod.mods_detail.nombre
    }

    private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit
            .Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://example.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
```

Los adaptadores y viewHolders funcionan correctamente y la conexion a la api es correcta

Actualizacion: Adjunto la excepcion

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.ddsc.app, PID: 6046
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 49 path $.results
```

Comment: Ya agregue el error :D

Comment: Encontré la falla del cierre, fue por que en en la interface, el json de la api mandaba una lista los resultados y lo tenia como objeto.

Comment: Ya pude solucionar los problemas, el del buscador no estaba relacionado directamente a la función de buscar.

La solución en general: 

-Recibir una lista en lugar de un objeto en la data class que recibe el JSON
-Colocar una comprobación antes de mandar llamar a Picasso por si existe un valor nulo o vacio :DD